# Java switching jpanels and new panel doesnt respond

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, keyevent

I start my game with a JFrame which starts a JPanel. That JPanel then moves on to the next one when its ready. I can switch to the new JPanel but it does not respond to my keypresses. The second JPanel previously worked fine so I think the issue is the switch between them. (I removed some methods that are unrelated)

```
public class GameRunner extends JFrame
{       
public GameRunner()
{
    super("Scrolling Shooter");

    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();  
    int width = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());  
    int height = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());  
    setSize(width, height);

    TitleScreen title = new TitleScreen(this);

    ((Component)title).setFocusable(true);
    getContentPane().add(title);

    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String args[])
    {new GameRunner();}
}

public class TitleScreen extends JPanel implements KeyListener, Runnable
{
private JFrame frame;           //the JFrame
private ImageItem background;   //the background
private String name = "";       //the player's name

/**
 * Constructs a title screen
 * @param f the JFrame
 */
public TitleScreen (JFrame f)
{
    frame = f;

    ImageItem fix = new ImageItem();
    fix.fixMainPath();              //fixes the main path for all the ImageItems
    background = new ImageItem(0, 0, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), "splashscreen.png");  //makes background stretch between the top and bottom walls

    setVisible(true);
    addKeyListener(this);   
    new Thread(this).start();
}

/**
  * Draws the stuff on the screen
  * @param g some Graphics object
  */
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    background.draw(g);
    if (!(name.equals("")))
    {
        g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(80f));
        g.drawString(name, frame.getWidth() / 3, frame.getHeight() - 60);
    }
}

/**
 * When a key is typed it is added to the name
 * @param key the key typed
 */
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent key) 
{
    if (!(key.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER))
        name += key.getKeyChar();
}   

/**
 * Enter makes moves to the game if the name is ok
 * @param key the key pressed
 */
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key)
{
    if (key.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
    {
        boolean isValid = false;

        if (name.length() > 20)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "That name is too long. Try again.");

        if (!name.equals(""))
        {
            try {if (!hasBannedWord(name)) isValid = true;}         //breaks the loop if there are no banned words in the name
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }

        if (!isValid)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Bad name. Try again.");
            name = "";
        }

        if (isValid)
        {
            ScrollingShooter game = new ScrollingShooter(frame, name);
            ((Component)game).setFocusable(true);
            frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
            frame.getContentPane().add(game);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    }   
}

public void run()
{
  try
  {
    while(true)
    {
       Thread.currentThread().sleep(0);
       repaint();
    }
  }     
  catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().sleep(0); repaint();` Not the correct way to do animation. Use a Swing `Timer` calling `repaint()` for animation.

Answer (score 1):

Use [the key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of `KeyListener`s, it provides better control over the focus level required to generate key events

In order for `KeyListener` to generate a `KeyEvent`, the component it is registered to must be focusable AND have focus.  There is no "easy" way to guarantee that a component can acquire/grab focus.

You should also consider using a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to move between your screens, it what it was designed for and will make life a lot easier

You should also call `super.paintComponent` to ensure that the component/`Graphics` context is prepared for painting

Comment: all the CardLayout examples show some buttons and stuff that I don't want. Is there a way to use cards in the background without attaching them to buttons?

Comment: CardLayout is a layout manager like any other, you simply add what ever containers you want displayed t the primary container and switch between the views as you want

Comment: I tried this but it only displays a blank JPanel. What is wrong?    `TitleScreen title = new TitleScreen(this);      ScrollingShooter game = new ScrollingShooter(this);

 JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
 cards.add(title, "title");
 cards.add(game, "game");
        
 CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
 cardLayout.show(cards, "title";`

Comment: Did you add `cards` to anything?

Comment: no I just did `cards.getLayout()` on the 2nd last line

Comment: You need to add the cards panel to somethinng that is displayable

Answer (score 1):

You're using a KeyListener and KeyListeners often have focus problems that are compounded if you try to swap them.

I suggest that you instead use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which can help you get around the focus problems, and that you swap your JPanels with a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).